# Sequelize on NodeJS/ExpressJS return an error when running CLI command db:migrate

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm following this tutorial [Using PostgreSQL and Sequelize to persist our data](https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/using-postgresql-and-sequelize-to-persist-our-data-c86854a3c6ac) on medium, and right now I'm stuck at the `db:migrate`. it's returning this error

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.1.0, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.8.2]

Loaded configuration file "config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Error parsing url: undefined
```

as you can see I'm using NodeJS version `12.1.0` and Sequelize CLI version `5.4.0` and Sequelize version `5.8.2` and all of them were the latest version.

and before running `sequelize db:migrate`, I'm running this command first `SET DATABASE_URL=postgresql://[user[:password]@][netlocation][:port][/dbname]` and it does not returns any error.

but it's returning error after I ran `db:migrate`

I already tried to find the problem, but I can't found the answer yet.
Here is my `./Models/Index.js` file.

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();

import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import { basename as _basename, join } from 'path';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const basename = _basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../../config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;
```

if you realize I just changed it to `ES6` format which change some codes, but before I change it to `ES6`, it doesn't work either. and for all the rest of the files I following the tutorial.

Here are the files that I think have a connection:

`.env`

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/test_app
```

`.sequelizerc`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "config": path.resolve('./config.json'),
  "models-path": path.resolve('./app/Models'),
  "migrations-path": path.resolve('./migrations')
};
```

`config.json`

```
{
  "development": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
  },
  "test": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
  }
}
```

If there are some files that I haven't included yet please tell me, and please help me to fix find the solution for this problem. Thank you

> OS: Windows 10

Comment: do you have gitbash?

Comment: yes I have, and I'm using VScode as well @aitchkhan

Comment: try the below solution then

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem? I am having the same Issue

Comment: @nnam4x Yes before I am able to solve the problem, but I forgot how to solve it as it's already been too long and I'm not using `NodeJS` anymore. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Basically you are unable to set environment variable `DATABASE_URL` successfully.

I am not a Windows guy, but this should do your job.

If you are using [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/download/win), then it is as simple as:

```sh
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/database_name
```

and after that:

```sh
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
```

**EDIT:**

I am not sure how to set this variable in gitbash and cmd.
Here is an alternate.

in `config/config.json`

```
"development": {
    "username": "postgres"
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "your_db_here",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
},
```

update these variables according to your postgres db.

and run:

```sh
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
```

Comment: So this line `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/database_name` is for set the URL to `environment variables on PC` ? if that's the case, is there any wildcard settings for it? so I can use it for another project as well? because from what I think it will only work for a certain project because the database name

Comment: This does not set the environment variable on your PC. This only sets the environment variable for the current shell session. You can do that separately for another project in its own shell session.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't work, Git bash doesnt recognized the export command

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already using it because I was stuck with my question, but still thanks for helping me :smile:

Comment: this will allow you to run migration atleast. I will try to solve the environment variable issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot fetch values at runtime inside config.json. It has to be static.
2. You should either use config.json or env variables or roll your own like mentioned in another answer.

To use env variables, you will eschew config.json. Instead, in models/index.js, set

```
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

to

`sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL)`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Sequelize migrations are a different beast than the normal sequelize workflow.

It is reading `config/config.json` when it loads - so you cannot use system environment variables - it has to be a static json file.

What I do in my projects, is having my `config.js` file making sure the config file is up to date with whatever settings I have.

I do this when the main program starts and also in `package.json` as follows:

(make sure to add `npm-run-all` to your `package.json`)

```
  "scripts": {
    "config": "node src/config.js",
    "_migrate": "sequelize db:migrate",
    "_migrate:status": "sequelize db:migrate:status",
    "_migrate:undo": "sequelize db:migrate:undo",
    "_seed": "sequelize db:seed:all",
    "migrate": "npm-run-all config _migrate",
    "migrate:status": "npm-run-all config _migrate:status",
    "migrate:undo": "npm-run-all config _migrate:undo",
    "seed": "npm-run-all config _seed"
  },
```

`config.js` simply does something similar to this at the end of the file:

```
// Export sequelize config/config.json for easy compatibality with sequelize-cli
const filepath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../config');
const filename = path.join(filepath, 'config.json');

fs.ensureDir(filepath)
    .then(() => fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(sequelizeConfig, 2) + '\n'))
    .catch((err) => console.error(`Failed to write config: ${err}`));
```

`sequelizeConfig` is should be the fully generated sequelize config object. You can also have a generic one like you have now, and build upon it.